# Selected items array not correct when using react native multiple select

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, multiple-select

I am using the code below to create a multi-select drop-down using react-native-multiple-select.

```
  onSelectedItemsChange = selectedItems => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
  };
     render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <MultiSelect
              hideTags
              items={items}
              uniqueKey="num"
              ref={(component) => { this.multiSelect = component }}
              onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
              selectedItems={selectedItems}
              selectText="Pick Items"
              searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Items..."
              tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
              tagBorderColor="#CCC"
              tagTextColor="#CCC"
              selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
              selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
              itemTextColor="#000"
              displayKey="gas"
              searchInputStyle={{ color: '#CCC' }}
              submitButtonColor="#CCC"
              submitButtonText="Submit"
            />
            <View>
```

My array looks like this:

```
data = [
         {gas:H2, num: 0},
         {gas:CO2, num: 1}
       ]
```

When I select the first 3 items my selectItems array is

```
[0,1]
```

It should display the array index that I selected which should be

```
[0,1,2]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are you accessing the array?

Comment: I have the array of options stored in a state called gasOptions. Then I set items in the MultiSelect props equal to {this.state.gasOptions}. To store the items selected I do the onSelectItemsChange line to add the item selected to the other state array I have called selectedItems.

Comment: Basically I need help trying to make an array to store the selected items.

Comment: are you logging the selectedItems somewhere? or is the out put of the selectedItems array after a submit?

Comment: I really have no idea what changed but now it is working. When I select the first 3 items I get an array of  [0,1,2].